# Conflicting answers regarding package from rpm, yum and repoquery

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, rpm

I have a few packages on a RHEL 6.5 system which exhibit the following puzzling behavior:

1. The package is installed;
2. `rpm -q` reports the package as installed;
3. `yum search` shows that the package is available out there;
4. But `repoquery --whatprovides` doesn't output anything.

An example:

```
$ yum install boost-openmpi
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do
$ rpm -q boost-openmpi
boost-openmpi-1.41.0-18.el6.x86_64
$ yum search boost-openmpi
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
==================================================================================== N/S Matched: boost-openmpi ====================================================================================
boost-openmpi.x86_64 : Runtime component of Boost.MPI library
boost-openmpi-devel.x86_64 : Shared library symlinks for Boost.MPI
boost-openmpi-python.x86_64 : Python runtime component of Boost.MPI library

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
$ repoquery --plugins --queryformat="%{NAME}_|-%{VERSION}_|-%{RELEASE}_|-%{ARCH}_|-%{REPOID}"   --all --quiet --whatprovides boost-openmpi
$
```

Is my understanding of yum, etc. correct that the last command should also return something if everything else before it reports that the package exists and is installed? (Pretty much all other packages installed on the system also report something at the `repoquery` step.) If my understanding is correct, how to I fix things so that repoquery finds the package again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yum search also looks at installed packages, use "yum search -v" to get the extra information (like where it was found). My guess is that you have these installed, but not available, you can easily check this with "yum list extras" (or better "yum list distro-extras", but I don't think that's in el6).

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. These packages are from "rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6.5.z", which it looks like is not enabled anymore. A note that `yum list extras` must be run as root to return meaningful results. If not run as root, it list all packages on the system, instead of printing a "please run this as root" error.